# Need a solution on dataset as given below

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
Data Set:
col1,col2,col3,col4.col5
(A,b,c,d,e)
(A,z,p,q,r)
(F,s,t,y,v)
(F,w,x,y,z)
(F,p,x,r,t)
(G,m,n,o,p)
(G,m,i,q,s)
```

Actually I need result set that has all the columns and only single row for each capital letter values among the all same capital letter values.

```
Result set should be like:
(A,b,c,d,e)
(F,p,q,r,t)
(G,k,i,q,s)

or
(A,z,p,q,r)
(F,w,x,y,z)
(G,m,n,o,p)
```

any of three rows.

> Actually I have detail records of so many companies in which some
>   where company name are redundant and I have to select single records
>   for each company on the basis of their name. Here I use Capital
>   letters for company name.
>
> I hope you realize the question well.
>
> Please provide a select statement I will be thankful to you all.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yeha I tried my basics sql like group by and joins... but not able to find the perfect solution . Thaks to SHARK. He provide the right soulution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
;with LetterSet as
(
    select *,
        row_number() over(partition by FirstCol order by SecondCol) as rownum
    from YourLettersTable
)
select
    FirstCol,
    SecondCol,
    ThirdCol,
    FourthCol,
    FifthCol
from LetterSet
where rownum = 1
```

Likewise, you could have `rownum = 2` for your second result set.

Comment: > over(partition by FirstCol order by FirstCol)
Shark, why not 
over(partition by FirstCol order by Col2, col3,...)
?
I think you'll can get different results between runs.

Comment: Ah good point.  Error on my part.  Fixed, thanks!